# Can Cassandra achieve stability with 2 nodes?

Tags: cassandra

Let me explain the current structure.

1. There are two physical servers.
2. And Cassandra is installed on each server.
3. This is the end.

The company built this system and told me: “It is a very safe structure.”

Here are the requirements for the project:

1. Even if one server is shut down, read and write operations can be performed on the remaining servers.
2. When a shut down server is restarted, all work performed on the remaining servers will be automatically synchronized (if not for a long time).

However, the above condition was a requirement that could not be achieved in the Cassandra technology theory consisting of two servers.

1. Not replicating properly
2. System gives up high availability for either reads or writes

I expect that no matter which setting you use, you will get either the above two or other bad results and your requirements will not be met.

I'd like to report on the instability of this system, but I'm not sure.

Are these project requirements actually achievable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that Apache Cassandra **may** fulfill the requirements:

- Cassandra is fault-tolerant for single-node outages, provided that replication and consistency levels are properly configured (more on this in the long answer)
- Cassandra manages data sync among replicas for missed mutations during a maximum unavailability period of 3h (by default)

For the long answer, you're unlikely to achieve high availability with only 2 nodes.

Firstly, it's important to grasp the fundamentals of the CAP theorem in distributed data stores. You can have:

1. High availability
2. Partition tolerance
3. High consistency

But only 2 of them.

In Cassandra, the tradeoff mostly lies in the balance between availability and consistency, which in turn are for the most part defined by replication and consistency level tuning.

The standard for production clusters is replication factor 3 per datacenter, meaning that each partition is replicated in 3 nodes per datacenter. That, in conjunction with consistency level `LOCAL_QUORUM` (which signifies the minimum majority of replicas) for the queries, means that only 2 replicas need to be available for each request, and therefore 1 node down is not a showstopper per se.

However, if either replication factor is less than 3, or consistency level is ALL (or a combination of both), high availability is lost, because `LOCAL_QUORUM` for 2 or 1 replicas is effectively the same as consistency level `ALL`. `ALL` is in itself an anti-pattern in Cassandra, since it defeats the purpose of high availability, which is one of the strongest selling points of Apache Cassandra.

As for data sync. For node outages lasting 3 hours or less, Cassandra uses [hints](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/stable/cassandra/operating/hints.html) to replay dropped mutations. Hints may take time to replay, and is one of the reasons that data consistency in Cassandra is categorized as eventual. Additionally, [anti-entropy repair](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/stable/cassandra/operating/repair.html) operations as frequent as the smallest [`gc_grace_seconds`](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/stable/cassandra/operating/compaction/index.html#the-gc_grace_seconds-parameter-and-tombstone-removal) are essential to guarantee data consistency over time.

There's considerable more nuance required to fully answer to the questions you posted, but in short I recommend the following to achieve the requirements:

1. Setting up **at least 3 Cassandra nodes** in a single logical datacenter
2. Ensure that the **replication factor** for all keyspaces is **3** (or more)
3. The **consistency level** for all queries is **`LOCAL_QUORUM`** (or less if you want to sacrifice some consistency in favor of availability)
4. **Repairs** are run every smallest **`gc_grace_seconds`**

Comment: Thank you for answer. My explanation wasn't enough. From what I know of technical theory, it should also meet the 4 items you recommended.
But even with two nodes, “high availability can be achieved,” “my company” tells me.

For this reason I need to explain the problem that arises using two nodes. Could you please explain in terms of the problem this will cause, rather than the solution?

Comment: I would need more contextual details to give a full answer, but you can achieve high availability with 2 nodes. The main problem with 2 nodes is that you have to choose between having (high availability and weak consistency) OR (low availability and strong consistency). 
With 3 or more nodes you can get the best of two worlds and have high availability and strong consistency, with some caveats on the consistency side.